# Replace Symbol With Number In Text Within frac(), Using Mathematical Annotation in R

Tags: r, math, annotations

Within my graph, I have included a label of the formula used to find the displayed data:

```
text(0,2,expression(paste(EMA[i], " = (", P[i], " x ",alpha,") + ", 
EMA[i-1], " x (1-",alpha,") where ",alpha," = ", frac(2,1+N))),adj=0)
```

The first question - The above is part of a function I am creating, which N is an adjustable argument.  I would like the N above, within the frac brackets, to display whatever value N equals when the function is run.  Is this possible?

Second question, how can I replace each "x" with the actual multiplication symbol.  I was unable to find this, the search is a nightmare.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, I'm null when it comes to expressions using math symbols in `R`, so I will *not* be answering the [main?] question. But as for the second question, I did `?plotmath` and it says `x %*% y    x times y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this using `bquote` instead of `expression` and wrapping the N in `.()`.  Also,  you can get the times sign by just using the appropriate Unicode character.

```
N = 3
plot(NULL, xlim=c(-1,4), ylim=c(-3,3))
text(0,2,bquote(paste(EMA[i], " = (", P[i], " × ",alpha,") + ", 
EMA[i-1], " × (1-",alpha,") where ",alpha," = ", frac(2,1+.(N)))),adj=0)
```

[image: Math expression]